# Get Checksum of file from webRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome extension that contains a whitelist of SHA256 checksums for javascript files. Only files within this whitelist are supposed to execute, all others should be blocked.

Currently, i use this **inefficient but working code** for getting a checksum and blocking the request.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.type == "script")
        {
            return getURL(details.url, false, function(data) {
                var content = sha256(data);

                if( hashList.indexOf(content) == -1 )
                {
                    console.error(details.url+" not in whitelist");
                    return {cancel: true};
                }
            });
        }
    }, {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"],
        types: ["main_frame","script"]
    }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

The problems with this code:

- It is quite inefficient as this requires downloading every file twice.
- It has to be running synchronously to stop the files before arriving at the client. This makes the delay even bigger.

I want to know / ask whether there are ways to circumvent those issues by accessing the source file without downloading it twice (didnt find anything in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)) or at least increase the performance by any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Cameron, unfortunately it is not possible to get the request body using webRequest API.

Partially this is correct because saving the content of a request may lead to performance problems. [See](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422) this discussion for more details.